# Multiple file extension in gridview

Tags: asp.net

Is there any way to pull multiple file formats from a source?
I am currently pulling all .jpg files but I like to be able to pull both .jpg and .pdf.

```
<itemtemplate>
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkParts" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("PartNumber") %>' 
NavigateUrl= '<%#Eval("PartNumber", "~/Hardware/{0}.jpg") %>'
</itemtemplate>
```

......

Comment: Is that inside a loop? Could you provide more context?

Comment: No, this is inside a gridview pulling data from column "PartNumber" of a table.

Comment: Could you edit your question adding the gridview code?

Comment: How do I add code here, it keeps telling me I have too many characters.